# window external null?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-7, window.external

When i want to use window.external on internet explorer 9, it's always null.
I want to use pinned methods but it cannot find the methods because of window external is null. 
if wonder that what is "pinned" you can check this link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg131029(v=vs.85).aspx
Can any body help me for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my IE9 typeof window.external returns "object" but I also don't have Pinned methods. Check your IE version for compatibility with pinned api first here (it will tell you if you need an upgrade)
http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Browser/SitePinning/Default.html?o=1

Regarding *window.external* it usually refers to additional level of Api when you use IE as a WebBrowser control in your app (hosting scenarious):

Window.external allows access to an additional object model provided by host applications of the Windows Internet Explorer browser components.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535246%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this problem. Apparently the methods on `window.external` exist but are "hidden" from JavaScript's methods of investigating an object. `window.external.somefuntion` will always appear to be undefined yet if you call the method (`window.external.somefunction()`) then the code will work.

Sadly this means the only way to safely call methods on `window.external` is to call the methods from with in a try-catch.